# Server not responding to multipart/form-data requests from Expo Go app

Tags: react-native, asp.net-core, expo, multipartform-data, ngrok

I currently have an ASP.NET Core Web API running on localhost:5000, and running on ngrok. I also have an Expo app running on Expo Go Android (physical device).

My server is not responding at all to a `multipart/form-data` request. However, a similar request made in Postman (using uploaded files instead of getting them from a URI) works. Which leads me to think that it's **probably something wrong on the React Native (Expo) side**.

On my server:

```
// Models/FileUploadRequest.cs
public class FileUploadRequest
{
    public IFormFile File1 { get; set; } = default!;
}

// Controllers/FilesController.cs
[HttpPost("Upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm] FileUploadRequest req)
{
    var file1 = req.File1;
    if (file1.Length > 0)
    {
        var safeFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        var safeFilePathName = Path.Combine(DANGEROUS_FILE_PATH, safeFileName);
        var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(safeFilePathName);
            await file1.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
    return Ok(new
        {
            Message = "File is uploaded",
            File = file1
        });
}
```

On the RN app, I'm creating a request like this:

```
// ...previous code that returns a `photo` object containing a URI to the temp photo file.
// Get image file from URI
const res = await fetch(photo.uri);
const img = await res.blob();

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('File1', img);
const uploadRes = await API.post('Files/Upload', formData, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
});
```

But whenever I try to send this request, **the server does not respond at all**. However, if I remove the headers (default `Content-Type: application/json`) then it does respond with `400`, along with these logs:

```
      Attempting to bind property 'Capstone.Features.File.FileUploadRequest.File1' of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile' using the name 'Fi
le1' in request data ...
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormFileModelBinder[19]
      Could not bind to model with name 'File1' and type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile' as the request did not have a content type of either
 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' or 'multipart/form-data'.
```

Comment: There is an issue with multipart/form-data when debugging is active?

Comment: @MichaelBahl This is an issue regardless of debugging (my current version of Expo can only check network requests on the Expo Go app itself, through "Show Element Inspector" > "Network"). According to the network tab, the request is sent successfully, with Content-Type: multipart/form-data and a file in its body. My API server doesn't react at all to it though. If I remove the Content-Type, then it does respond, but with (rightfully) a 400 Bad Request error, along with the logs at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the `server side` code but for `React Native` you can try to modify your code as follows:

```
const res = await fetch(photo.uri);
const img = await res.blob();
let formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append("File1", {uri: photo.uri, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg'})


fetch('your-server-url',{
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  body: formdata
  }).then(response => {
    console.log("image uploaded")
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })  
});
```

P.S: You can change `image/jpeg` to other content type based on your requirement.

**UPDATE**

The problem is `formData.append('File1', img)` because `React native JSC` does not support `File` and `Blob`, so you have to use libraries.

[react-native-fetch-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob) has very good support for this. You can check out the example provided by the same.

Comment: Thanks for the update. My Expo version runs on Hermes, not JSC, so I'm not sure if that's even the problem. I never thought of the Blob as being the problem though, I'll look into that lib